# Counting elements in nested table by name starting with

Tags: lua

I have the table listed below

```
raids = {
    {
        T1I0 = {
            {'Mightstone of Sargaras', 'Mightstone of Sargaras\n\nMightstone of Sargaras is obtained by farming. GL'}
        },
        T1I1 = {
            {'Blessings Jewel of Elune', 'test'}
        },
        T1I2 = {
            {'Lifegiving Gem of Amanthel', 'test'}
        },
        T2I0 = {
            {'Practicing monster pot', 'test'}
        },
        T2I1 = {
            {'Nuwa stone', 'test'}
        }
    }
}
```

I've managed to count the amount of elements `T1I0` -> `T2I1` = 5 by using the function below, combined with `tablelength(raids[1])`

```
function tablelength(T)
  local count = 0
  for _ in pairs(T) do count = count + 1 end
  return count
end
```

But I'm having some problem with counting only elements starting with `T1`, sound return `3`.

Anyone got an ide how I can modify the last part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
  for k in pairs(T) do if k:sub(1,2)=="T1" then count = count + 1 end end
```

However, consider re-structuring the table in two layers, the first one having keys `T1` and `T2`. After this, the count you want is simply `#raids.T1`.

Comment: You are a bloody genius. Thanks alot for your time.